# Why android 5.0 occur error java.lang.RuntimeException: start smooth zoom failed?

Tags: android-camera

This is my code set zoom of camera:
// 10 Set zoom value to camera

```
                if (p.isZoomSupported() && p.isSmoothZoomSupported()) {
                    // most phones
                    mCamera.startSmoothZoom(zoomvalue);
                } else if (p.isZoomSupported() && !p.isSmoothZoomSupported()) {
                    p.setZoom(zoomvalue);
                    mCamera.setParameters(p);
                    mCamera.setParameters(p);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                }
```

But it occur exception on Canvas Spark (Q380)  android 5.0:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: start smooth zoom failed
    at android.hardware.Camera.startSmoothZoom(Native Method)
    jat android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2775)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2326)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8687)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4485)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4343)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3884)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3937)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3903)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4013)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3911)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4070)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3884)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3937)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3903)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3911)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3884)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6300)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6256)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6209)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6462)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6421)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6493)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:795)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:598)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:565)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:781)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

Why android 5.0 occur error java.lang.RuntimeException: start smooth zoom failed?